# Does temporary object creation depends on the C++ compiler?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

Does temporary object creation depends on the compiler?

In the code bellow, I call a function sending a char* but the function requires an Object reference. However, Object has a constructor that uses a char*.. So a temporary object is automatically created and send to the print function.

```
class Object {
    string text;
  public:
    Object ( const char* value ) { text = value; }
    void print() const { printf( "[%s]\n", text.c_str() ); }
};

void print( const Object& obj ) { obj.print(); }

int main() {
    print( "hello" );
}
```

Does this behavior depends on the compiler?
You can see the output here: http://codepad.org/AABw5Ulz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare such a constructor

```
 Object ( const char* value )
```

it means the compiler can do an *implicit conversion*.

So no it is not a compiler dependent feature but it is by desing.

The compiler is simply allowed to take your `"hello"` and pass it to the `Object` contructor before sending it to the `print(const Object &obj)`function.

Comment: I don't think "the compiler is allowed" is the right expression. There is no other way to do it, the compiler is *required* to construct an `Object` instance as the argument for the function call.

Comment: Ok, so no matter what compiler I'm using, I'm NOT forced to write print( Object("hello") ); which would be very annoying...

Comment: Yes Kerrek SB, It's allowed, but I wasn't sure if it was going to make that decision, or just show a compiling error.

Comment: @NIGO: Correct, you can rely on so-called *implicit conversion*, which is provided by any constructor that is callable *with one single argument* (and not declared `explicit`).

Answer (score 3):

Your case is pretty clear-cut. This isn't even a situation where temporaries may or may not be elided. Rather, your `print` function *requires* an `Object`-type argument, so one will necessarily have to be constructed.

There isn't any room for alternatives in your situation, so there's nothing that *could* depend on a compiler. If you wanted a situation that left room for optimizations, you could consider passing the argument by value: `void print(Object);`. Now it's up to the compiler whether the temporary object gets copied once or constructed directly in the target function. That's because copy constructors are explicitly allowed to be elided.